# Meta tag with dot in key is not recognized

Tags: typo3, meta-tags, typoscript, typo3-11.x

Microsoft would like to find this tag in my `<head>` part:

```
<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="5..............................Z" />
```

So I write:

```
page.meta {
  msvalidate.01 = 5..............................Z
}
```

However that tag appears only if I remove the dot.

I also tried

```
page.meta {
  ["msvalidate.01"] = 5..............................Z
}
```

This does not help.

Can I help by reporting this as bug, or is there another solution to this?

---

**Edit 5.1.23 13:54**
TYPO3 Version 11.5

Comment: I know about `page.headerData.10 = TEXT ... ` it's just ugly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the dot:

```
page {
  meta {
    msvalidate\.01 = 5..............................Z
  }
}
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/12.4/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#meta

Comment: Thank you so much. Why didn't I think of the nearest idea ^^ Escaping the dot works for sure in TYPO3 Version 11.5.

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

```
page.meta {
    msvalidate\.01 = 5..............................Z
}
```

(you didn't tell which TYPO3 version you use)

Comment: Thank you so much. Why didn't I think of the nearest idea ^^ Escaping the dot works for sure in TYPO3 Version 11.5. // I accepted Mathias' answer, which was 1 minute before. Thank you anyway.